# Showing IP in browsers instead of Domain after migration to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have migrated my website to the Google Cloud servers. I have pointed the old DNS to the Google DNS and I have setup the DNS zone with an A record for the main domain pointing to the IP of the Google Cloud server and a CNAME record for the www subdomain. However, when I type the domain name in the browser, it loads the Google Cloud IP, but the browser doesn't show the domain name but the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one DNS entry for the instance;

`www` aliased (`A`) to the (external) IP address of the server.

Answer (score 0):

**From your description I guess that you configured your Cloud DNS in a correct way** and that your domain registrar is pointing to GCP DNS servers:

```
nameServers:
- ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.
```

**Nevertheless make sure your DNS configuration looks similar to this:**

[image]

If you need to add some records to your DNS here's some usefull documentation on [how to add records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records#adding_a_record) to do it. You can use both console or `gcloud` utility for this.

You may also have a look at the documentation on [how to migrate to GCP from other providers](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating).

**But - I suspect some tricky-webserver configuration issue here. Why ?**

You pointed out that you can reach your website - but instead of domain name you see a real IP of your site in the browser. That may be the result of a specific configuration that "redirects" you to a certain IP after detecting you used domain name to get to the server.

Please inspect your webserver's configuration and try to point out a real cause of this.